# Casting datetime to varchar in scalar-valued function SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, type-conversion

I'm trying to get the following statement executed. The scalar-valued function is expecting a `varchar` for the date and the original column in `customertable` is a datetime. I've done my research and looked around; the various solutions I've tried haven't worked.

When I run this:

```
select 
   ID, DATE_COL,
   dbo.CustRandValuationOnDate (ID, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATE_COL, 120), 10)) 
from customertable
```

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data
>   type.

UPDATE: function code

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CustRandValuationOnDate](@DATE VARCHAR(11), @CIFNUMBER VARCHAR(12)) RETURNS FLOAT
 AS BEGIN
 RETURN ISNULL((SELECT SUM(DBO.RandValOfAccOnDate(@DATE, A.ACCOUNTID))
         FROM   ACCOUNTTBL A, BALANCETBL B
         WHERE  A.CIFNUMBER=@CIFNUMBER
         AND    B.ACCOUNTID=A.ACCOUNTID
         AND    B.VALUATIONDATE=@DATE), 0.00);
 END
```

UPDATE: some of the values in DATE_COL are null. ive just confirmed that.

Comment: What does your string contain??

Comment: you mean the date_column? it contains timestamps in date_time format and unfortunately a lot of them have NULLs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing your params in the wrong order to function..

Comment: yes i am. it works now. im very sorry for wasting your time guys. o_O.

Answer (score 1):

OP says `DATE` is a datetime so:

```
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), 10)
```

is valid and works, as does:

```
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, NULL, 120), 10)
```

As a result, the error must be in your `dbo.CustRandValuationOnDate()` function.  Without that code, there is no way to solve this.  Perhaps, `dbo.CustRandValuationOnDate()` needs to be written to handle NULL input values.

**EDIT** after function code posted:

```
RETURN ISNULL((SELECT SUM(DBO.RandValOfAccOnDate(@DATE, A.ACCOUNTID))
                                                ^^ID?   ^^date??
```

parameters in wrong order?

you define the function parameters as: `@DATE VARCHAR(11), @CIFNUMBER VARCHAR(12)`, but call it with `ID, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATE_COL, 120), 10)`, so what are you really trying to do?

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, KM. will post function code now.

Comment: +1 fwiw - OP should have made this the accepted answer because it's the only answer that finally lead to the solution presented by you and others.

Comment: @Lieven, thanks.  yea, I posted about the parameters in wrong order first (edit 2: Jun 24 at 11:45)

Answer (score 0):

Instead for Converting in to Date you can Use `Cast(YourVariable As Date)` for converting in to DateFields.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. i just realized something confusing in my question. DATE is the name of the date column, not the DATE datatype. please see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to re-write your scalar function  dbo.CustRandValuationOnDate to recive a datetime. after in this function, first validate it is null.

After, make the cast to varchar and use the LEFT function.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
select    ID, DATE_COL,   dbo.CustRandValuationOnDate (ID, 
LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATE_COL, 120), 10)) from customertable where ISDATE(DATE_COL) = 1
```

Comment: the `DATE` column is a datetime data type, so `where ISDATE(DATE_COL) = 1` will always be true, you could try `WHERE DATE IS NOT NULL`, but that would result in a different result set and may not be what the OP wants

Comment: thanks for your response, terence. i tried it that way and i got this error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2001-04-01' to data type int."